# calling a plug inside __before_compile__ does nothing

Tags: macros, elixir, metaprogramming

I am trying to get my head around the elixir module lifecycle and one thing that I have noticed is that calling a plug macro in the **before_compile** block doesn't execute the plug when the calling the controller. It was my understanding that this block executes right before compilation so the plug macro would also be compiled in the module.

For given this:

```
  defmacro __before_compile__(env) do
    quote do
     plug :say_hi
    end
  end
```

With a method in a phoinex controller:

```
def say_hi(conn, _) do
   IO.inspect("hello")
end
```

This will not print hello, where as having the same quoted block in a **using** block will. What am I missing?

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Per the relevant documentation on `Module` and compilation callbacks](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Module.html#module-compile-callbacks), `__before_compile__` needs to invoked in the target module with `@before_compile MyApp.MyModule` (where `MyApp.MyModule` is the name of your module).

If you're trying to make `__before_compile__` happen in another module that `use`s your module, you can define `__using__` *and* `__before_compile__`, like so:

```
defmodule MyApp.MyModule do
  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      @before_compile MyApp.MyModule
    end
  end

  defmacro __before_compile__(env) do
    quote do
      plug :say_hi
    end
  end
end
```

The [Sugar web development framework](https://github.com/sugar-framework/sugar/blob/master/lib/sugar/controller.ex#L59) has a relatively simple real-world demonstration of how this works in its controller code; when you call `use Sugar.Controller` in a controller module (say, `MyApp.Controllers.Main`), the `Sugar.Controller.__using__/1` macro is invoked, which in turn causes `@before_compile Sugar.Controller` to be invoked in the context of `MyApp.Controllers.Main`, thus doing a bunch of behind-the-scenes Plug-related magic (mostly implementing the `Plug` behavior, but that's a bit beside the point here).

Phoenix also does similar similar things with its controllers, though with a bit of indirection; [`Phoenix.Controller.Pipeline`](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/master/lib/phoenix/controller/pipeline.ex) is another good demonstration of this pattern (albeit more complex).

---

On an unrelated note, I've had very mixed results with getting `IO.inspect` or `IO.puts` (or `IO.`anything, for that matter) to actually show up in this sort of situation.  You might want to try `require Logger; Logger.info "hello"` instead.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear, yeah I understood this infact I am doing exactly this and yet I have no hello output.

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  In that case, seeing the actual code both in the controller and in the module containing the `__before_compile__` and `__using__` definitions would be helpful.

Comment: Theres a bunch of things in here. Let me see if I can recreate with the bare bones and ill ping up a gist

Comment: Also, see my recent edit at the bottom of the answer; have you tried using `Logger` instead?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/chrisjowen/393d27b5286658fd0ed21d3195d3afb6, I'll try logger now

Comment: No joy with logger Im fairly convinced this is not working, and this is the correct behaviour. Now im just trying to figure out why :)

Comment: It would probably help to see the code for `PitchhunterApi.Web` and possibly even `PitchhunterApi.Router`.

Else, is there a specific reason why just sticking to `__using__` is insufficient?

Comment: This was just a vannila phoenix app with only that route in. For my use case (not this simple example) I can't do it in `__using__` because I first retrieve all the module attributes on methods and add them to another attribute `@method_annotations`.  This is not available until the `__before__compile__` stage for me. My goal really was to be able to add `@authenticate true` above controller methods and have plugs called for that method.

Comment: Ok I figured out the fix, not sure exactly the reason though. But adding the `@before_compile` above the `PitchhunterApi.Web :controller` part worked. Correct me if I'm wrong but I __think__ this is because this uses Plug modules that invoke there own `__before__compile__` before mine so my plug is not in the modules attribute list at this time.